# How come Postgres.app doesn't start psql

Tags: macos, postgresql, osx-mavericks

I have downloaded and opened postgres.app

According to their [docs](http://postgresapp.com/documentation), I should now be able to run `which psql`. In the terminal. This renders nothing. I'm running mavericks. How can I debug this problem or solve it?

Comment: Is it anywhere in your launchctl agents?

Answer (score 1):

Check your PATH and make sure it includes the folder where the psql program exists.

If not, add it to your bash profile:

```
PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin:$PATH"
```

http://postgresapp.com/documentation

Comment: I got the following response (two versions running?) 495 - 0x7f8ea2f04ee0.anonymous.postgres
488 - com.heroku.postgres.72896

Comment: it's not in the launchAgents folder either.

Comment: And I didn't use homebrew, but rather the postgres app.

Comment: My bad, I thought psql was available but you couldn't connect to the server. Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks! Though I had to add it to bash_profile that already existed (for MAMP).

Comment: Here is a thread for any future internet travellers: https://github.com/PostgresApp/PostgresApp/issues/137